# not getting values which are added dynamically from the component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-forms, angular-dynamic-components

I am trying to get the values of dynamically added component on click of save button.

Here is [get-dynamic-added-component-values](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-dynamic-added-component-values-ulaj2k)

**ts:**

```
postData: any[]=[];
  finalObject;
  saveData(form : NgForm) {
    this.postData = form.value;
    let jsonData = this.postData; <-- I am not getting all values
  }
```

Here I will get values which is default added, when I click on `Append to tab` button, new component will be added and on click of `save` button all values will be printed in ts file (`saveData()`) function.

Answer (score 0):

I could see only `configselectedLinkTo-1`    value is undefined that's because it's type is hidden

```
<input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="selectedLinkTo1" name="configselectedLinkTo-1" />
```

Comment: this is not an issue. Issue is I am not getting all the values If I add component dynamic.

Comment: Click on `append to first` button, add values and check console, yow will not get all values those you have entered.

Comment: are you getting this?